# Smiley Rating Bar swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ratingbar

If we had to do this [Smiley Rating Bar](https://github.com/sujithkanna/SmileyRating) on iOS...how we can do?

1. In the link-example, use a gif, but let's avoid this
2. If I had to do it ... I would use 5 images of faces for the background with their respective descriptions.
3. For the face that moves in its position X would use `UIPanGestureRecognizer`:

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController  , UIGestureRecognizerDelegate , UITextFieldDelegate{

   @IBOutlet weak var image1: UIImageView!

   var panGesture  = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.draggedView(_:)))
       image1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
       image1.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
   }

   func draggedView(_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
       self.view.bringSubview(toFront: image1)
       let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
       image1.center = CGPoint(x: image1.center.x + translation.x, y: image1.center.y)
       sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

       }
   }
   ```

> The question I have is how do I move the image1 to detect what is going on "above" the images below. Like this:

[image]

So...any help I will appreciate

Comment: I'd use `UIBezierPath` (for the eyes and mouth) and animate them according to the position of the "smiley".

Comment: According to the position of that translation change the image of the above imageView , put the background images in a stackView with equal widths to correctly figure the position

Comment: I hope in your design `UIView`->(5) `UIImageView` with equal width. So, you can find your current pan based frame, also in 5 image view position.
 Otherwise, Try [Lottie animation](https://www.lottiefiles.com/), May help look like animation.

Comment: Like Larme said, use a UIBezier and interpolate the progress value from the smiley xPosition. You may want to look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator too.

Comment: @xhinoda .. did u implement this .. if yes please tell me the process ?

Comment: may be it will help you try it..@al_mukthar https://github.com/gali8/G8SliderStep

Comment: @xhinoda were you able to achieve this? Please help me out.

Comment: @HardikAmal not exactly like i want..but you can use: https://github.com/gali8/G8SliderStep

Answer (score 5):

```
I have done the same thing, Please use
```

https://github.com/gali8/G8SliderStep/tree/master/G8SliderStep Library .Please replace the Draw labels and Draw Images method with following in G8SliderStep.swift File.

```
 @objc internal func drawLabels() {

    guard let ti = tickTitles else {
        return
    }

    if _stepTickLabels == nil {
        _stepTickLabels = []
    }

    if let sl = _stepTickLabels {
        for l in sl {
            l.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        _stepTickLabels?.removeAll()

        for index in 0..<ti.count {
            let title = ti[index]
            let lbl = UILabel()
            lbl.font = unselectedFont
            lbl.text = title
            lbl.textAlignment = .center
            lbl.sizeToFit()

            var offset: CGFloat = 0
            if index+1 < (steps%2 == 0 ? steps/2+1 : steps/2) {
                offset = trackLeftOffset/2
            }
            else if index+1 > (steps%2 == 0 ? steps/2+1 : steps/2) {
                offset = -(trackRightOffset/2)
            }
            if index == 0 {
                offset = trackLeftOffset
            }

            if index == steps {
                offset = -trackRightOffset
            }

            let x = offset + CGFloat(Double(index) * stepWidth) - (lbl.frame.size.width / 2)
            var rect = lbl.frame
            rect.origin.x = x
            rect.origin.y = bounds.midY - (bounds.size.height / 2) - rect.size.height + 80
            lbl.frame = rect
            self.addSubview(lbl)
            _stepTickLabels?.append(lbl)
        }
    }
}

@objc internal func drawImages() {
    guard let ti = tickImages else {
        return
    }

    if _stepTickImages == nil {
        _stepTickImages = []
    }

    if let sl = _stepTickImages {
        for l in sl {
            l.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        _stepTickImages?.removeAll()

        for index in 0..<ti.count {
            let img = ti[index]
            let imv = UIImageView(image: img)
            imv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            imv.sizeToFit()

            var offset: CGFloat = 0

            if index+1 < (steps%2 == 0 ? steps/2+1 : steps/2) {
                offset = trackLeftOffset/2
            }
            else if index+1 > (steps%2 == 0 ? steps/2+1 : steps/2) {
                offset = -(trackLeftOffset/2)
            }

            if index == 0 {
                offset = trackLeftOffset
            }

            if index == steps {
                offset = -trackRightOffset
            }

            let x = offset + CGFloat(Double(index) * stepWidth) - (imv.frame.size.width / 2)
            var rect = imv.frame
            rect.origin.x = x
            rect.origin.y = bounds.midY - (bounds.size.height / 2)
            imv.frame = rect
            self.insertSubview(imv, at: 2) //index 2 => draw images below the thumb/above the line
            _stepTickImages?.append(imv)
        }
    }
}

Please get selected and unselected emoticons image from your personal resource, and pass those image in array as done in given example.In your view controller in viewDidLoad please write this code:
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        sliderStepBar.stepImages =   [UIImage(named:"terrible")!, UIImage(named:"bad")!, UIImage(named:"okay")!, UIImage(named:"good")!,UIImage(named:"great")!, ]

        sliderStepBar.tickTitles = ["Terrible", "Bad", "Okay", "Good", "Great"]
        sliderStepBar.tickImages = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "unselectterrible"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "unselectbad"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "unselectokay"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "unselectgood"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "unselectgreat")]
        sliderStepBar.minimumValue = 4
        sliderStepBar.maximumValue = Float(sliderStepBar.stepImages!.count) + sliderStepBar.minimumValue - 1.0
        sliderStepBar.stepTickColor = UIColor.clear
        sliderStepBar.stepTickWidth = 40
        sliderStepBar.stepTickHeight = 40
        sliderStepBar.trackHeight = 5
        sliderStepBar.value = 5

    }
```

Enjoy the Smiley Rating.
Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

I have created the same, Check the below image

[image: SampleRating]

**Overview**

1. Easy customization(Font, Colors, Images, Ticks, Height, Width, Rounded)
   @IBInspectable
2. Tappable
3. Draggable
4. Swift 5.0 above
5. Xcode 11 above
6. Orientation support
7. Manual drag & drop the class

Find the GIT URL for code

[SmileyRating](https://github.com/Sivabalaa/SmileyRating)